# How to get a simple plot with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, graph, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have this code:

```
plot = pg.PlotItem()
plot.plot([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], symbol='o')
viewer = pg.ImageView(view=plot)
self.tabLOs["Server"].addWidget(viewer)
```

to do a quick proof-of-concept for making a few simple graphs to display system data.  I want a very simple graph that I can update as the data comes in.  The code above gives me a graph but with an interactive area to the right.  I've found other classes that give me just graphs, but they aren't able to be used with addWidget and/or have the plot() method.  Is there a PlotItem equivalent that doesn't have all the extra stuff that I can just add to an existing layout with addWidget?

EDIT: pg is from "import pyqtgraph as pg" and tabLOs["Server"] is just a VBox layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create a [`pg.PlotWidget`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/plotwidget.html#pyqtgraph.PlotWidget) which can be added to your `QVBoxLayout`. You can then get the plot item using `my_plot_widget.getPlotItem()` (this method negates the need to create your own `PlotItem`).

Comment: Perfect.  Worked like a charm.  For future readers, I switched to this:
plot = pg.PlotWidget()
pi = plot.getPlotItem()
pi.plot([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], symbol='o')
self.tabLOs["Server"].addWidget(plot)